# Unwanted output when using Response.Flush()

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net (.aspx) page containing a button. When I click that button I wish for some content (given as a byte array and created in my code-behind) to be written into a text
file and downloaded to the user (Open\Save..).
I use the following button click handler syntax:

```
  Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + "non-queries.txt");
            Response.BinaryWrite(\*Here I send the byte array*\);
            Response.Flush();
```

Now the content of the byte array does get written into the file, but what also gets written is the html content of the aspx page containing the button, which I don't want written.

Can you help? Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `Response.End()` should do the trick. I had a similar problem and this resolved the issue for me. See [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593607/response-flush-writes-html-for-page-on-windows-vista-7-8-but-not-on-server-200/15605609#15605609).

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `Response.Clear();` at the top and see if that solves your problem. You can also add `Response.ClearContent();`.

Comment: The thing is it writes the byte array content AND BELOW the content of the aspx page.

Comment: Ah it's Below. How about if you add `Response.End();` after `Response.Flush();`? Using `Flush()` will only tell the server to send the current data, it doesn't end the response. Try that.